# Creating arrays that aren't indexed properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out someone else's code that doesn't work at my company any more.

I have a variable set `$row[9]`. The data is from a CSV file that the php parses. The var_dump looks like this

[image]

When I try to put `$row[9]` into an array by doing this `$school = explode(",", $row[9])` 
`var_dump($school)` outputs this.

[image]

`print_r($school)` outputs this.
[print_r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLgRd.png)

Shouldn't `$school` look something like this below?

```
     [0] => array(1) {[0] => string(8) "2/3-AM"}
     [1] => array(1) {[0] => string(8) "2/3-AM"}
     [2] => array(1) {[0] => string(8) "1/2B-AM"}
```

Let me know if I need to add any other information.

Comment: Can you try with `print_r` ?

Comment: I think your issue is just format if you do foreach($schools as $school) you will be able to access the info.

Comment: Hey I updated the post with the print_r. I can access the info using foreach afterwards but then when I need to combine another array with it does the same thing and doesn't index the arrays so I can't call to certain ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears if the first screenshot is all values that `$row[9]` takes. As if it is iterating over a list, `$row[9]` has multiple values between the beginning and end of execution. It is not an array of all of those values; it is each of those values individually.

If you were to `explode(',', $each_value)`, then each value will become `array( [0] => $each_value )`, since each value does not contain a comma.

Given you anticipated output, it seems you expect `$row[9]` to be an array of those strings, when it is simply a string that changes value over time.

Comment: That makes sense. So would there be a way for me to create an array with those individual values of $each_value?

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to change the original code. Create an empty array at the start of the file, such as `$row9_values = array();` and then for each iteration, do something along the lines of `array_push($row9_values, $row[9]);`. At the end of the file, you will have the array of all values that `$row[9]` took throughout execution.